# Unity JsonUtility ArgumentExсeption

Tags: c#, .net, unity3d

Задача: сделать десериализацию из строки json и поместить ее в переменную. Все дело происходит в Unity

Код:

```
[Serializable]
    class packageF
    {
        public player[] players = null;
    }
    class player
    {
        public string name;
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public int Class;
        //int anim;
        //bool isRight;
    }
    packageF CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<packageF> (jsonString);
    }
```

Когда я использую CreateFromJSON(json), выдает исключение `ArgumentException: JSON must represent an object type.`

Что делать?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста пример json на котором у вас возникает ошибка

Comment: vmchar, {"players": [{"name": "Oleg", "x": 1, "y": 2, "Class": 0}] }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте пометить ваш класс `player` атрибутом `[Serializable]`, потому что без атрибута у вас получится сериализовать только типы знакомые юнити (например массив int), но не ваши кастомные типы.

Также имейте в виду, что сериализатор юнити не поддерживает null.

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогли!